# Split the string using Regex with the special characters

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have a string as **[@variable] -eq 'some value'** or **'some value' -eq [@variable]** and i want to split it using Regex.

The expected output is as below

1. [@variable]
2. -eq
3. 'some value'

or

1. 'some value'
2. -eq
3. [@variable]

I have the used regular expression **\w+|'[\w\s]*'** to match and split the string but it gives me below output

1. variable
2. eq
3. some value

which ignores the special characters with the string.

Can anyone please help me on this?

**EDIT**

The answer by **lbrahim** is working for most of the scenario but failing when the value is date time.

**[@variable] -eq 'MM/dd/yyyy'**

The above expression should also work for the same

Comment: split on spaces which exists before non-word characters. `\s+(?=\W)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\[?\@?\-?\w+\]?|\'[\w\s\/]*\'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KMWtZY/10)

Or this:

```
-\w+|\[\V*\]|\'\V*\'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KMWtZY/11)

Comment: @lbrahim Thanks for your answer. It is working fine but now got another scenario where i have the string as [@variable] -eq 'some value' where value is date like '11/15/2016'. So the above regex is failing for [@variable] -eq 'MM/dd/yyyy'

Comment: @User5590 You're welcome. I updated my code to include stuff like '11/15/2016' .